# android webview get clicked images links?

Tags: android

i have small project its content `listview` and each item inside `listview` content html `webview` and the webview content `text` and `images`

my problem is i can't get the image `src` on click

so i want to get clicked image `src` without opening the image inside the `webview`

i've tried to add `<a href` to the images but when i clicked on the image its open inside the `webview` i don't want that all i want to get the image `url` when i click on it is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is if you are using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` then you can check the url for image types:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url == null){
      return false;
    }else if (url.trim().toLowerCase().endsWith(".img")) {//use whatever image formats you are looking for here.
      String imageUrl = url;//here is your image url, do what you want with it
    }else{
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank u very much this is what aim looking for but still i have a problem when i clicked on `<a href="adf.jpg"><img src="imgs.jpg" /></a>` its open inside listview , how i can stop the action onclick if its image ?

Comment: How are you handling this inside of the ListView? Can you update your original question with some code so I can have a better idea of how to help?

Comment: i didn't create the listview yet aim working on simple webview activity just for test if i success ill continue to listview, so my idea is if user clicked on image i can open clicked image by android gallery got it ? can i do this or forget about it?

Comment: you should be able to open it with the gallery using an `Intent` or `Intent Chooser` Maybe this could help: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html